# Wifi not working properly in HP 15AC 650TU

Tags: wireless

I have a HP 15AC-650TU. It had pre-installed Windows 10. As I'm not a Windows fan, I completely formatted the laptop to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In Windows 10 wifi used to work properly but in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS wifi is not working properly. At boot it works fine. Then after someone the wifi range goes down and it loses the connection completely. I have already consulted some other sites and it says that most of the HP users have the same problem with their laptop too after installing the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS/14.04 LTS. It's either the kernel problem or the their is no proper driver installed for my Realtel PCI controller. Is there anyway I can use other kernel or is there any proper version of driver available for Ubuntu. Please somebody know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have problems with wifi at both my desktop and laptop, if the signal gets lost and then up again then the wifi, sometimes, can't reconnect (even with disabling-enabling wifi, but most of the times that fixes the problem). The only thing I can do is run in terminal 'systemctl restart NetworkManager' and the wifi works again. You can create a .desktop file on your desktop with this command so that you execute it every time you have problem. I don't know any other solution.